# I want to insert a data from a form into a table, and select another data from another table and insert into third table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have three related tables “users”, “category” and “interest_area”; and I want to insert a data from a form into “users” table, and select another data from “category” table and insert into “interest_area” table using PHP.

**The error it shows is:**

> Error: INSERT INTO users(user_id, first_name, last_name, higher_education, user_name, pass_word) VALUES('' , '87878787' , 'iuiu' , 'iuiu' , 'root' , '');INSERT INTO interest_area (category_id) SELECT category_id FROM category WHERE category_name = 'ASP';
>   Erreur de syntaxe pr�s de 'INSERT INTO interest_area (category_id) SELECT category_id FROM category ' � la ligne 2

**My PHP code is:**

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST["interest_area"])){             
   $f_name = $_POST["firstname"];
   $l_name = $_POST["last_name"];
   $h_education = $_POST["higher_education"];
   $i_area = $_POST["interest_area"];
   $email = $_POST["email"];
   $u_name = $_POST["user_name"];
   $p_word = $_POST["pass_word"];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO users(user_id, first_name, last_name,   higher_education, user_name, pass_word)
  VALUES('' , '$f_name' , '$l_name' , '$h_education' , '$username' ,  '$password');";

  $sql .= "INSERT INTO interest_area (category_id)
    SELECT category_id FROM category
    WHERE category_name = '$i_area';";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";} 
else { echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;} 
}
?>
```

Comment: you can't have multiple statements in a single query call.  It's a basic defense mechanism against one form of sql injection attack. You have to have TWO $sql variables, and call `query()` separately for each.

Comment: What about `mysqli_multi_query()` @MarcB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run two mysqli_query for insertion

[mysqli_query](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp)

**Better use prepare statement while insertion of data**

[prepare statement](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

```
$f_name = $_POST["firstname"];
$l_name = $_POST["last_name"];
$h_education = $_POST["higher_education"];
$i_area = $_POST["interest_area"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$u_name = $_POST["user_name"];
$p_word = $_POST["pass_word"];
$user_id = $_POST["user_id"];
```

`$user_id` should not be blank if it ur primary key then data can't be inserted;

```
 $sql1 = "INSERT INTO users(user_id, first_name, last_name,   higher_education, user_name, pass_word)
      VALUES('$user_id' , '$f_name' , '$l_name' , '$h_education' , '$u_name' ,  '$p_word')";

 $sql2 = "INSERT INTO interest_area (category_id)
     SELECT category_id FROM category WHERE category_name = '$i_area'";

 mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
 mysqli_query($con,$sql2) 
 mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to run your two `INSERT` statements as separate `$conn->query` calls, rather than concatenating them into a single call.

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax error is here:

```
$sql .= "INSERT INTO interest_area (category_id)
SELECT category_id FROM category
WHERE category_name = '$i_area';";
```

should be in curly...

```
$sql .= "INSERT INTO interest_area (category_id)
SELECT category_id FROM category
WHERE category_name = {$i_area};";
```

And two separate queries as stated...

Comment: Outright **FALSE**. There's nothing wrong with OP's string syntax. That's perfectly valid PHP

Comment: Sorry... our shop uses curly for more clarity... single quote is valid...

Comment: removing the quotes will just make it an bare string, and probably a syntax error as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use multi_query for multiple queries.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users(user_id, first_name, last_name, higher_education, user_name, pass_word)VALUES('' , '$f_name' , '$l_name' , '$h_education' , '$username' , '$password');";

$sql .= "INSERT INTO interest_area (category_id)
     SELECT category_id FROM category WHERE category_name = '$i_area'";

 mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql);
 mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Make sure you have the syntax right - each query needs its own semi-colon on the SQL statement.